# Can you execute a /fill command based on another player's coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a way to make a fill command that fills where another player is. I know you can do it to your own coordinates using the ~ ~ ~ keys, but can you do it to another player/entity? I'm not willing to download a mod though.

Comment: I just want to clarify: execute as 1 player filling at the location of another?

Answer (score 3):

### 1.13+

`execute`'s `at` subcommand allows you to change where the command is running. For example, the following command will fill glass around a random player:

```
execute at @r run fill ~2 ~2 ~2 ~-2 ~-2 ~-2 glass
```

Any [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors_In_Java) can be used in place of the `@r`, or just a player name, to select the player/entity you want.

---

### 1.12-

The `execute` command will change who the command is running as and where it's running from. For example, the following command will fill glass around a random player:

```
execute @r ~ ~ ~ fill ~2 ~2 ~2 ~-2 ~-2 ~-2 glass
```

Comment: This is a good time